# jQuery $.ajax call for obtaining RESTful API from cross domain URL but it doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp, restful-url

The error message is

> Console Error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"
>
> STATUS: parseerror,
>
> ERROR: jQuery1110072177085862495_1399027696440 was not called

My ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({ 
   crossDomain: true, 
   url: "54.225.213.167/developer-assessment/api",
   dataType:"jsonp", 
   type: "GET" 
})
  .done(function(data, status, xhr){ 
       console.log(data); 
})
  .fail(function(xhr, status, error){ 
       console.log(status); 
       console.log(error); 
);
```

Even if the result calling the url directly is a JSON obj.

Comment: Looks like server doesn't return jsonp, but json

Comment: Yes I've written that at last post's line.

Comment: There are many examples available. Server doesn't return jsonp but does it support CORS, cross domain requests? If no you have to proxify request server side (same domain as your current page).

Comment: just checked, server doesn't handle cross domain request. Can you modify htaccess on this server, if ya, allow request from all or specific domain (better regarding security)

Comment: No, I can't modify .htaccess.

Comment: So then, you have to proxify request from your own domain, e.g http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/ Of course, you could use a server side script from other domain than current page and makes it returning jsonp but i guess you get the idea